# Getting Extra information while wrapping List<Objects> in http JAX RS response

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

```
        {
"context": {
    "headers": {},
    "entity": {
        "validationDetailsEntityList": [
            {
                "createTimestamp": 1512653225936,
                "modifyTimestamp": 1512653225936,
                "version": 0,
                "auditTimestamp": "2"
            },
            {
                "createTimestamp": 1512652876650,
                "modifyTimestamp": 1512652876650,
                "version": 0,
                "auditTimestamp": "2"
            },
            {
                "createTimestamp": 1512652955832,
                "modifyTimestamp": 1512652955832,
                "version": 0,
                "auditTimestamp": "2"
            }
        ]
    }

"entityType":"com.example.demo.wrapper.ABCDWrapper",
"entityAnnotations": [],
```

> Class Written below to get the response on the http mapped request

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fetch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response getAllXYZDetails(@RequestBody QueryDetails queryDetailsPayLoad) {

        List<XYZEntity> xyzEntityList =  xyzService.getAllXYZDetails();
            return  Response.ok(xyzEntityList)
                        .build();
```

}

I am trying to build a generic response type from my controller class on http REST calls, and so my return type is Response.
Now, what's happening is that:
The response generated not only has the details that I want in json but also it is having a lot of extra information like 
**entityType** and **entityAnnotations** etc etc(SEE ABOVE RESPONSE), which I don't want.
How to get rid of those ans get only the entities in response?

Comment: Can you post the  validationDetailsEntityWrapper class structure?

Comment: public class ValidationDetailsEntityWrapper implements MessageBodyWriter<ValidationDetailsEntity{
    private List<ValidationDetailsEntity> validationDetailsEntityList;

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson annotations you can configure pretty much everything. In your case, `@JsonIgnore` should suffice.

If you are using JAX-RS/JAXB then Add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on top of your class

Comment: This is the direct response from jax rs core.. I cannot modify that. I think I can write a wrapper on top of this. But need some idea. Did you get my point?

Comment: Share your code by editing your question for class you are trying it. And yes you should return back the root class of your .